# Principal divisor of degree $\neq 0$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider the curve $$C:x+y+y^3+x^4=0\subset\mathbb{A}_k^2.$$
I want to calculate the principal divisor of $f:x+y\in k(C)$.

Since $f$ has no poles in $C$, we just look at point $(a,b)\in C$ with $a+b=0$. That is $(0,0)$ and $(1,-1)$.

We have $v_{(0,0)}(f)=1=v_{(1,-1)}(f)$. So the principal divisor is $$\operatorname{div} (f)=1\cdot(0,0)+1\cdot (1,-1).$$

Is this right so far?

Now consider the homogenization $\widetilde{C}$ of $C$, that is $$\widetilde{C}:x_0^3x_1+x_0^3x_2+x_0x_2^2+x_1^4=0\subset\mathbb{P}_k^2.$$ The points with $f(a:b:c)=b+c=0$ on $\widetilde{C}$ are $(1:0:0)$ and $(1:1:-1)$. So the divisor of $f$ on $\widetilde{C}$ is $$\operatorname{div} (f)=1\cdot(1:0:0)+1\cdot (1:1:-1).$$

Now my question:

> I have learned that the degree of a principal divisor on a projective curve is equal to $0$. But here we have $\deg \operatorname{div}(f)=2\neq 0$. So where is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the "point at infinity" on your projective curve, namely, $[0:0:1]$.

To deal with the point at infinity, write $f = x_1/x_0 + x_2/x_0$ so that $f$ is well-defined on the entire projective curve. Go to the affine chart $[x_0 : x_1: x_2] = [u: v: 1]$, where the equation for the curve becomes
$$ u^3 v + u^3 + u + v^4 = 0$$
and $f = 1/u + v/u$.

The point at infinity is has coordinates $(u,v) = (0,0)$. Notice that $v$ is a local paramater here and $u = -v^4/(1+u^2+u^2v)$ has valuation $4$ in the local ring, so $v_{[0:0:1]}(f) = -4$.

Also, $v_{(0,0)}(f)$ is not $1$. $y$ is a local parameter at $(0,0)$ and $f = y^3 + x^4 = y^3 [1+ y(1+y^2)^4/(1+x^3)^4]$ in the local ring at $(0,0)$, so $v_{(0,0)}(f) = 3$.

Now the sums work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54342/discussion-between-mathmarseille-and-kenny-wong).

Comment: Can you please have a look in the chat? :) One more question arised.

Answer (score 0):

The local description of $f=x+y$ corresponds to $\frac{X+Y}{Z}$ in homogeneous coordinates. So you're going to pick up a pole at $[0:1:0]$.

Comment: You mean $(0:0:1)$?

Comment: No I do mean $(0:1:0)$.  The homogenized equation is $XZ^3 + YZ^3 + Y^3Z + X^4=0$. And $\frac{X+Y}{Z}$ has a pole at $(0:1:0)$.

Comment: How do I get the corresponding function $(X+Y)/Z$?

Comment: Kenny explained it above. His $x_0$ is my $Z$, his $x_1$ is my $X$ and his $x_2$ is my $Y$.